# Auxiliary table

Tags: python

I have a base like this:

| COD_PRODUTO | PRODUTO | DATA | FILIAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABACATE | 2022-03-22 | LOJA A |
| 3 | MAÇÃ | 2022-03-15 | LOJA B |
| 1 | ABACATE | 2022-03-22 | LOJA C |
| 2 | UVA | 2022-03-15 | LOJA D |
| 1 | ABACATE | 2022-03-15 | LOJA E |
| 3 | MAÇÃ | 2022-03-15 | LOJA F |

I want the table to look like this:

| COD_PRODUTO | DATA_01 | DATA_02 | VENDAS_DIAS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-03-15 | 2022-03-22 | 2 |
| 2 | 2022-03-15 | 2022-03-15 | 1 |
| 3 | 2022-03-15 | 2022-03-22 | 2 |

That is, I want to count how many times the product was sold, but only once a day (date) regardless if it appears 200x in a single day it will be counted once on that day and I move on to the next one and the new df needs to receive the sum of these days according to the table above.

I'm trying in Python.

Thanks

```
def agrupa_e_conta_vendas(df):
    # agrupar as vendas únicas por dia para cada produto
    vendas_unicas = df.groupby(['PRO_CD', 'DATA'])['QTD_VENDA'].nunique().reset_index()
    vendas_unicas.columns = ['PRO_CD', 'DATA', 'VENDAS_UNICAS']

    # converter a coluna DATA para o tipo datetime e criar uma nova coluna mês-ano
    df['DATA'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATA'])
    df['MES_ANO'] = df['DATA'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m')

    # agrupar por produto, mês-ano e somar as vendas totais
    vendas_totais = df.groupby(['PRO_CD', 'DATA'])['QTD_VENDA'].nunique().reset_index()
    
    novo_df = vendas_totais
    return novo_df.head()
```

This code above is what I did, but it went wrong

Comment: HI Renato, Stack Overflow is an English-only site - try [Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com) or editing this question with a translation

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a better way to do this, bt i hope this kinda helps you:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({"COD_PRODUTO":[1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3], "PRODUTO":["ABACATE", "MAÇÃ", "ABACATE", "UVA", "ABACATE", "MAÇÃ"],
        "DATA":["2022-03-22", "2022-03-15", "2022-03-22", "2022-03-15", "2022-03-15", "2022-03-15"],
        "FILIAL":["LOJA A", "LOJA B", "LOJA C", "LOJA D", "LOJA E", "LOJA F"]})
df = data.groupby("COD_PRODUTO")
ven = df['DATA'].nunique()
dates = list(df['DATA'].unique())
dates_fix = []
for i in range(len(dates)):
  if len(dates[i])<ven.max():
    temp = list(dates[i])
    for j in range(ven.max()-len(dates[i])):
      temp.append(dates[i][len(dates[i])-1])
    dates_fix.append(temp)
  else:
    dates_fix.append(list(dates[i]))
output = pd.DataFrame({"COD_PRODUTO":data['COD_PRODUTO'].unique()})
for i in range(len(dates_fix[0])):
  output["DATA_" + str(i+1)] = list(zip(*dates_fix))[i]
output["VENDAS_DIAS"] = list(ven)
print(output)
```

Output:

```
   COD_PRODUTO      DATA_1      DATA_2  VENDAS_DIAS
0            1  2022-03-22  2022-03-15            2
1            3  2022-03-15  2022-03-15            1
2            2  2022-03-15  2022-03-15            1
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!!!
Sorry for the delay in responding, but I've been busy here. Your code worked great!